I am having an issue uploading an image with Django
I am currently working my way through a django project and am having trouble working with MEDIA and uploading an graph image.
Inside settings.py, I have added the below code.
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

HomePage.html:
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}image.png" alt="Uploaded Image" style="max-width: 100%; height:     auto;">  

HomePage->urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Relative Path from the html file to the image: media/graph/upload/image.png
I get the error
Not Found: /graph/upload/image.png.

Main Project
--App
----settings.py 
--HomePage 
----HomePage.html 
----urls.py
--media 
----graph 
------upload 
--------image.png

Thank you for all your help! Let me know if you need anymore of the code, I just didn't want to make this super long if this is a simple error.
I've also tried hardcoding the path to the directory and that did not work either so I think I am misunderstanding something with Django.

What's the final rendered URL in the img src? Are you setting the MEDIA_URL template variable yourself or are you using django's built-in media context processor?

@CoffeeBasedLifeform hey,  I am not setting the Media_URL myself.  Do I need to do that somewhere?  I eventually will be passing in the file name like this


Victor Duarte's answer below describes how you can have Django add the MEDIA_URL variable to the template context so that you can use it in a template. With your settings, {{ MEDIA_URL }}image.png will produce the url /media/image.png. Given the directory structure, you probably want {{ MEDIA_URL}}graph/upload/image.png, though.

@CoffeeBasedLifeform thank you so much, you and Victor got it working!

if you want to use {{ MEDIA_URL }} in your templates, add django.template.context_processors.media in the context_processors option of TEMPLATES.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.media"
            ],
        },
    },
]


This worked!  Thank you!
